# How are shaders represented in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

I've been looking into how shaders are compiled into WebAssembly, but I can't seem to find any examples. Ideally I am looking for an example that spits out a `.wast` with the shader compiled.

Does anyone know where I could find some examples (that hopefully create the intermediary `.wast` files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAssembly currently talks to the web platform exclusively through JavaScript. Interacting with the GPU is therefore done from WebAssembly by calling imported JavaScript functions, or by having JavaScript functions read the `WebAssembly.Memory` which the program fills with information needed to draw things.

Shaders therefore work exactly the same way they do for JavaScript.